# Why is my Openshift deployment not changing my webpage?

Tags: java, git, openshift

Although, I deployed my webapp which is a restful webservice app to Openshift, I cannot see any result in the webpage.

I have just a JSP which says "Hello World" but OpenShift still shows me the "getting started page" when I access to the URL and also when I ping the webservices I've just get 404.

The response from git push is:

```
remote: [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d/app-root/runtime/repo/target/granojobackend.war
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 14.300s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 17 06:50:43 EDT 2016
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/158M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 639a5131
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Starting PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: jbossews process failed to start
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d/jbossews
remote: #<IO:0x000000014283c0>
remote: #<IO:0x00000001428348>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
To ssh://56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d@granojobackend-f1987.rhcloud.com/~/git/granojobackend.git/
   98751dc..55bc085  master -> master
```

So, my question is... which is the URL I need to ping? I tested /granojobackend but it is not working. 
Is there anything else I need to do?

Another question.. is it possible to use Openshift with Java1.8 and Tomcat 8? In Openshift I'm using java 1.7 and Tomcat 7, but I want to move to tomcat 8 and java 1.8.

Comment: You're URL is not working, because your build is not working.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I guess the line that said that is Activation status: failure... Do you see which is the error in that log?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are missing the `openshift` profile on your `pom.xml`

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

You should have something [like this](https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-java-tomcat-application-for-free-on-openshifts-paas/):

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>app_name</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... now I get:
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/56e7f1bc89f5cf8c7000003d/jbossews
remote: #<IO:0x00000002345380>
remote: #<IO:0x00000002345308>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed

Comment: Go ahead and send us the full log by using something like pastebin.com